# Function Key causing problems

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, function-keys

I just switched from XP to Windows 7.  Also got a new USB Slim keyboard (Lenovo).   I can't use any of the function keys without suppressing the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key with it.   For example, I use to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> to run a macro.   Now I have to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd>.   Can this be removed?

Answer (score 1):

In my lenovo (Edge 520) pressing the fn key a while (like 4 seconds) shows a popup where you can disable this.

Discovered today by accident :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the BIOS for the Fn key lock.  Also this driver might help: http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/MIGR-75582.html

Comment: Where would I go to check the bios?   Thanks.

Comment: Usually during boot up there is a key to press to enter Setup or bios settings.  I do't know for sure on your PC.